# I was unable to install mysql in my ubuntu OS

Tags: permissions, mysql, password, root, localhost

I was following [this guide](https://support.rackspace.com/how-to/installing-mysql-server-on-ubuntu/) to install mysql. Later it asked for password and since I was installing that time, I directly pressed enter as there was password. After that it was showing this error:

```
/usr/bin/mysql -u root -p
Enter password: 
ERROR 1698 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'
```

Comment: It is unclear why you are "unable to install mysql". You should provide the output of the installation command. Note, running the shell, and installing are not the same.

Comment: Check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39281594/error-1698-28000-access-denied-for-user-rootlocalhost), it talks about similar issue

Answer (score 0):

As I understood, you installed mysql without root password (by mistake).
According to this [link](https://www.percona.com/blog/2016/03/16/change-user-password-in-mysql-5-7-with-plugin-auth_socket/), you can solve your problem by doing the following.

in the terminal run:

```
sudo mysql
ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'password';
```

Where `password` is a new password for the root user.
Also, don't forget to restart mysql using `sudo service mysql restart` after altering the user's password.